# I am trying to read bytes from a file and the tab character is getting skipped

Tags: c++, file

So here is the code I'm using to read from the file. I am trying to read every byte in the file which includes values from 0x00 to 0xFF. However for some reason 0x09 gets skipped. In the ascii table 0x09 is the Tab character.

```
typedef unsigned char byte;

std::ifstream fin;

fin.open(fileName, std::ios::binary);

byte input;
std::vector<byte> fileContents;

for (int i = 0; i < 4096; i++)
    {
        fin >> input;
        fileContents.push_back(input);

    }
```

Is there any reason 0x09 gets passed over?

Here is a link to the file

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9LMmsGNPg7UaVcwbWRsNi1xMFk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: How is the file you try to read constructed?

Comment: Don't use the formatted (and text-based) input operator `>>` input when reading binary data. Either use [`read`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read) (or alternatively [`get`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get)) which are unformatted.

Comment: your question is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18022074/c-sharp-hex-byte-0x09-ascii-tab-to-t-string#.just try .

Comment: @Anirudh - although I'm not sure a C# question is going to provide a suitable solution ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`operator>>` is a [FormattedInputFunction](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/FormattedInputFunction) for every overload except the streambuf.

You don't want formatted input, you want the raw characters; as Joachim says, use [read](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read) or [get](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get).

As an aside, why are you using `unsigned char` if you want characters? `std::istream` has `char_type=char`, so you should probably match that.